# New Consumer Group Picks Messages from Beginning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I had a Kafka consumer annotated with StreamListener without any group id. Now when I added the group-id via `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group` it started processing all the older messages from the beginning which were already consumed by this consumer when it did not have the group-id.

How can I configure it to pick only the unprocessed messages which were not picked before?

I tried adding `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.startOffset` to latest and resetOffsets to true but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already given a group id (which is a required property, and I'm assuming spring generated one for you), then setting the starting offset or auto.offset.reset will not take affect.

You can change the ID again for those to work, or you can use Kafka cli tool to adjust the group to the offsets you want

Comment: I created the new group id but it still picks from the beginning. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1016

Comment: The responses you got are the same as I stated: a group is created if you don't set one, if you do set a brand new one, then it'll only use the reset features. If you want to pickup where you previously left off with the generated group, you need to find it's name and manually commit those back into your new group name. Otherwise, you read from the beginning and establish a way to handle duplicates in your downstream consumers and restarting that app would continue to pick up the most recent committed offset (I assume you use auto commits?)